# Analysis of repeated measures when fixed effect changes within-subjects?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, glmm

I'm helping a colleague with a repeated-measures analysis in which each subject's fixed effect changes over the course of data collection.  He's measuring a continuous, positive response variable (Response) in agricultural plots (ID) (which themselves are grouped within Blocks) as a function of Crop type.  The response variable is measured 4 times over the course of the season.  The analysis would normally look something like this:

```
modelout <- lmer(Response ~ Crop + (Month|ID) + (1|Block) , data=cropdata, 
                 family=gamma(link="inverse"))
```

However, just to make things complicated, the first measurement is done prior to planting, so it's influenced by the *previous year's* crop type.  That is, for plot $A_1$, Month 1's Crop is Wheat, but Month 2-4's Crop types are Barley.  Is there any way to analyze this in a single model?

Alternatively, I see two options:

1. Analyze Month=1 separately from the repeated-measures analysis for Month=2-4;
2. Use compound fixed effects, e.g., Wheat-Barley, Wheat-Corn, etc.

Any suggestions?

Edited to add: another thought - can we just add the first month's response and crop types to the model as covariates (continuous and categorical, respectively)?