# analysis of repeated measures not over time

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I had a look to these posts [Analysis of repeated measures when fixed effect changes within-subjects?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66396/analysis-of-repeated-measures-when-fixed-effect-changes-within-subjects), [Repeated measures analysis... or not?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89530/repeated-measures-analysis-or-not), however they don't fit to my study since my data is not longitudinal.
Here is a summary of my study design, I have two groups of patients (cases and controls), in each of them I have two measurements from the same tissue but in two different locations (proximal and distal). These two samples  are taken from the same tissue (knee) for each patient and control.

So far, my design (I think) has two between-subjects (grouping) factors: status (case/control) and location (proximal/distal).

I would like to test the differences between cases vs controls but taking in account location, and also which is the effect of the location in these differences.

My measurement variable is genetic expression (RNA-seq values). I was thinking of using a linear mixed model including location as random effect:

```
lmer(status ~ age + sex + 1|location + 1|subject)
```

Would this approach appropriate or should I use a simple non linear regression including `location` in the formula?

my data set contains a matrix with genes in rows and individuals (or samples in columns) and then I have a metadata with the description of the individuals. The two files would look like this:

A) metadata info

```
   sample   location  sex type  age  status
indv_1001          1    M   CT   31       0    
indv_1002          2    M   CT   49       0                     
indv_2001          1    F   CT   45       0                     
indv_2002          2    F   CT   48       0                                             
indv_3001          1    F   CT   71       1                                             
indv_3002          2    F   CT   61       1                                             
indv_4001          1    M   CT   26       1                                             
indv_4002          2    M   CT   24       1
```

Samples `1001/1002` are from same individual, the same for `2001/2002` and so on.

B) Expression matrix

```
GeneID  indv_1001 indv_1002  indv_2001  indv_2002
Gene 1     84.438     99.49     51.312     44.866
Gene 2    233.355     99.49     60.642     47.072
Gene 3     59.874     99.49     91.429     51.485
Gene 4     46.824     99.49     94.228     54.427
Gene 5     56.803     99.49     61.575     58.84
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does each patient have proximal and distal measurements? Can you also clarify why you say you have three measurements but then say These two measurements? You could edit in the first few lines of your data-set if that is easier than trying to explain in words.

Comment: @mdewey, I just edited the post, all the patients and controls have proximal and distal measurements.

Comment: That seems to suggest that if x001 and x002 are the same individual they all change sex?

Comment: I don't see anything random about the location. That appears to be a fixed effect. You should not model it as a random effect anyway if you only have two values for the grouping variable. Remember, you are trying to estimate a variance with a random effect.

Comment: thanks @Roland, should I model the location like this: lmer(status ~ age + sex + location + 1|subject)

Comment: Yes, you probably should. But also investigate interactions. E.g., we know that men and women age differently.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, if you write the comment as an answer I will granted the answer

Comment: Just an observation, but going on the example it looks like the outcome variable of your model `status` is a binary variable. If this is the case a linear model is not appropriate and you should look into logistic regression.